# Magento 2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'quoteData' of undefined

Tags: magento2

/checkout/ page (for “one page checkout” mode)
“Cannot read property "quoteData” of undefined" from quote.js
The error is coming from OOB quote.js, so tried creating a custom version by adding 'domReady!' and still not working.

I tried different ways but the error came up again after few days in our testing/lower environment but same code works fine in production site. We saw this error few days ago but went away after clearing cache but showed up again.

Tried adding 'domReady!' as suggested at [Github post](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14412) and [mage2pro topic](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/1412) but still no luck. Clear cache, upgraded as well bunch of times. Magento CE version 2.2.6.

Getting this error when going to next page from shopping cart(checkout/).

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'quoteData' of undefined
    at quote.js:33
    at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
    at Object.context.execCb (resolver.js:145)
    at Module.check (require.js:866)
    at Module.enable (require.js:1143)
    at Module.init (require.js:774)
    at callGetModule (require.js:1170)
    at Object.completeLoad (require.js:1544)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptLoad (require.js:1671)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved after fixing DB connection details in one of OOB template file.

Comment: Could you please post the solution?

Comment: Issue was the DB connection configuration in one of the file, that had incorrect information, so it couldn't connect to DB to load data.

Comment: can you put details information how you fixed this?

Comment: Interested in getting the answer too !